# Printing 2d Array in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a problem with return the string[][]. I cannot return the whole array
and the second problem is

```
@language[$id] = [@$eng];               
@return  = [[@language[$id]],[@$eng]];
```

when I use the foreach to loop through the 2d array (@return). it gives me some output as 
word:

ARRAY(0x30ae1b4) ARRAY(0x30ae1e4)

... Hello.2.....

word: ARRAY(0x30ae534) ARRAY(0x30ae574) ...

Please help...

```
sub nextWord{

    my @return = [];
for my $id(1 .. 3) 
{
                my $eng = $db->selectall_arrayref("select word from words 
                                                left outer join language
                                                on words.languageId = language.languageId
                                                where words.languageId = $id
                                                order by word asc                   
                                                ;"); #limit 10 offset $currentOffset                                            

                @language[$id] = [@$eng];               
                @return  = [[@language[$id]],[@$eng]];
                foreach my $row (@return)
                {
                    print "word: @$row ...\n";
                    print " Hello.". @$row.".....\n";
                }       

$currentOffset+=10;
}return  @return;
```

}

Comment: Please go read [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). They are invaluable for understanding Perl references and complex data structures like the ones you keep having troubles with.

Comment: @CanSpice I think that was suggested to the OP several times from previous questions.

Comment: @DVK: I'm hoping eventually it'll sink in.

Comment: I've flagged this user for moderator attention, due to the number of nearly-identical questions she is posting, without heeding the advice she is being given.

Comment: @Winnie - You have asked a nearly identical question several times before. If you can give me a compelling reason _why_ this one is strikingly different, I'll reopen it. Until then, I'm closing this.

Comment: @Ether, perhaps you can take some time to edit this, so the OP actually gets the answer that they want? I tried, but got stuck in ambiguity. In either event, please flag for moderator attention once edited.

Comment: @Tim: I'm not sure what she's asking either. The answers have made a good stab at it though.

Answer (score 2):

```
@language[$id] = [@$eng];
```

should be

```
$language[$id] = [@$eng];
```

---

I don't understand what you want to store in `@return` but you are storing the wring thing.

```
@return  = [[@language[$id]],[@$eng]];
```

You are assigning an array reference.

Did you read perldoc perldsc as people have advised you previously, as well as other perl references?

---

If you want to loop over the results of `selectall_arrayref`, you can do:

```
foreach my $row (@$eng) { # What the hell is $eng anyway? Use meaningful variable names please
    print "Word: $row->[0]\n";
}
```

---

If you want to assign an arrayref of words from your query into a `$language[$id]`, Dre's answer is good

Answer (score 1):

DVK is partly correct, however selectall_arrayref already is returning an 2d array:

```
[ ['word1'], ['word2'], ['word3'] ]
```

You will need to do something like:

```
$language[$id] = [ map { $_->[0] } @$eng ];
```

Comment: is that what he was trying to do? I completely didn't get the actual desired logic.

Comment: that's the best I can tell, at least

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete DVK answer : in perl, the @ sigil is used to refer to the whole array, or a sub-array. Individual array elements (or hash elements) are scalars, so use the $ sigil.

To illustrate Dre answer, I'll add that if your scalar contains an array or hash reference, you can dereference it by preceding it with the correct sigil :

`$scalar = [ 1, 2]; @array = @$scalar`

You can also refer to a sub-array which is itself an array:

`my @array = qw( this that goat cheese);
print @array[2,3];`

This displays 'goatcheese'.